# Haskell-stack is giving "Download expectation failure"

Tags: haskell, build, dependencies, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use stack to build a project, and I'm receiving 'Download expectation failure' when running 'stack build'.

```
C:\Users\T60\Dropbox\notebooks-stack>stack build
Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC
Download expectation failure: content hash (SHA512)
Expected: aa1178f08ad3364c504ee790dac9b0774b7461fa7ea0a8f2c3ad82943d109602debcf4
a8a83090815fef487ceac40019f8b5594ab0043f36e019d69bc5f76853 (ByteString)
Actual:   91f514e1731ef3c2063ff5ab6156242755b2b2b462d4a1f40f150d96cf714f7b7b5b19
c7705e5129bbb9876216ca86ff52e49cd7604d83e4b4150172c9bda228
For: https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/hackage.fpcomplete.com/package/SHA-1.6.4.2.tar
.gz
Pr
```

The relevant portion of my cabal file is:

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                       , bytestring
                       , sqlite-simple
                       , time
                       , SHA
```

I've traced the error message to the `show` instance of `VerifiedDownloadException` in Verified.hs in the stack source code, but for what this actually means (something dumb in my cabal file, bad package on stackage, internal error in stack...) I have no idea.

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: Is this condition permanent?  It should recover from this issue and try again.  What version of stack are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a bug in stack, where a corrupted download would fail to be properly redownloaded. It's been fixed in the latest builds.